# TTFB waiting time is high in Cake PHP AJAX requests

Tags: php, ajax, apache, request, cakephp-3.0

My cake php 3 application running on apache server that take 2+ seconds in every ajax request for `TTFB` waiting time. Even the ajax response is empty everything, it takes such long time for waiting.

Is there any configuration or solution for to minimize the waiting time ?

Comment: Questions like this have been asked many times before, do a little research, do some debugging, find out if and where the time is spent on the server side, and once you have that informatio,n and you still cannot solve the problem on your own, check back and add the gathered information to your question.

Comment: @Miuranga Did you find anything? I am facing the same problem.